# How to construct base class multiple times in derived constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

Hello I I have problem on my assignment which I need to init base constructor which is point multiple time in derived constructor which is polygon.

The polygon have at least 3 point , each point have a coordinate value. any one have  ideas how to init base constructor multiple time in constructor init?
The inheritance ideas is not my ideas , is the assignment question.

this is the question

Polygon  (constructor) creates a polygon with npoints vertices, the vertices take their values from those stored in the array points. Note that the array points should not be assumed to persist; it may be deleted after the constructor is invoked.

```
struct PointType
{
  float x;
  float y;
};

class Point 
{ 
public:  
  Point(const PointType& center );
  virtual ~Point();  
 private:
  PointType m_center;
};

class Polygon : public Point
{ 
public:  
  Polygon(const PointType* points, int npoints);  
  ~Polygon();  
  const VectorType& operator[](int index) const;  
  private:
  int m_npoints;
  Object::PointType * m_pt;
    }; 


#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include "Object.hpp"
using namespace std;


const float eps = 1e-5f;

bool Near(float x, float y)
{
  return abs(x-y) < eps;
}


float frand()
{
  return 10.0f*float(rand())/float(RAND_MAX);
}


int main()
{
  srand(unsigned(time(0)));
  int count = 0,
      max_count = 0;

  // Polygon tests
  int n = 3 + rand()%8;
  float *xs = new float[n],
        *ys = new float[n];
  float x = 0, y = 0;
  PointType *Ps = new PointType[n];
  for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    xs[i] = frand(), ys[i] = frand();
    Ps[i] = PointType(xs[i],ys[i]);
    x += xs[i], y += ys[i];
  }
}
Point::Point(const PointType& center)
: m_center{center}
{

}

 // this is wrong, can correct me how to construct it?
 Polygon::Polygon(const PointType* points, int npoints, float depth)
   :m_npoints{npoints} , m_pt{new Object::PointType[npoints]}, Point    (*m_pt ,depth)
{
  for(int i=0; i < m_npoints ; ++i)
  {
    m_pt[i] = points[i];
  }
}

    enter code here
```

this the assignment structure like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMXQW.png)

I took away other object class implementation

Comment: If polygon is supposed to have multiple points then inheritance is not a suitable choice. Use aggregation (of vector<Point>) instead.

Comment: It should not be *"is"* relationship. Polygon *is not* a Point, Polygon *has* Points.

Comment: Go for composition. Polygon has points.

Comment: is the assignment they set to use inheritance , not I choose it.

Comment: Then either assignment is rubbish or you misunderstood it.

Comment: I would like to see that assignment, it sounds like one of two sides misunderstands of what they actually want.While it is possible to go with template instead, that would be completely different barrel of red herrings. You can though both inherit point and compose points into class (that would make it a non-standard layout object) but in that case you wouldn't use the  parent at all.

Comment: I update the question, maybe u can enlighten me what it mean

Comment: im not sure what this do `PointType *Ps = new PointType[n] `? are you trying to instantiate a PointType object?

Comment: Whoops, we stepped on each other's toes here. I reworked your question, you can find my edit in the [revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52493493/revisions) if you want to merge it with yours.

Comment: Whoever is teaching you this, does not understand what Object Orientation means. If you can, stop listening to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a trick question, is actually want me to find centroid point of polygon.

So I need a private compute center point of polygon function and return the result of center point of polygon, and then call the function in point constructor when init.

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment text doesn't say anything about inheritance. It essentially describes composition. Go from here:

```
class Polygon
{ 
public:  
  // constructor should allocate the array
  Polygon(const PointType* points, int npoints);  
  ~Polygon();  
private:
  Point *m_npoints; // or use smart pointer if you're allowed to.
 };
```

Comment: neither raw pointer nor smart pointer is appropriate here, use `std::vector`

Comment: @sp2danny they never allow them in those assignments.

Comment: @clarenceng alright, now I recognize example from one  book of  early 89 year. The inheritance does nothing to way you store with that diagram, it's likely for type erasure. You still need an array of points of some sort inside of the polygon.